# Alter column properties in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make a change to the data type for a column in an existing table. This column currently is empty but the table has dependencies which makes it impractical to drop and recreate the table.

The table currently looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[van_Payment](
    [PaymentUID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SponsorshipUID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PaymentMethodUID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Amount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Created] [int] NOT NULL, 
 GO
```

I need to change the following:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[van_Payment]
ALTER COLUMN [Created] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
GO
```

I am getting the following error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'DEFAULT'.

Any help with the correct syntax would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it possible to add `default constraint` using `alter column` syntax. Try this.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[van_Payment]
ALTER COLUMN [Created] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL 
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.[van_Payment] ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Created DEFAULT getdate() FOR [Created];
```